# Calculate metrics LiDR

Tags: lidar, lidr

Would it be possible to calculate a density metric in height intervals as in FUSION or Lastools?
e.g number of all returns between 0.2 and 3 meters/number of total returns in 1 meters cell. 
I'm trying to compute using the function of the package `stdmetrics_z(z)` but I had an error with `fast_table`

```r
myMetrics2 = function (z) { 
  n = length(z)
  zmax = max(z)
  zmean = mean(z)
  if (zmax <= 0) {
    d = rep(0, 9)
  }
  else {
    breaks = seq(0.2, 25, 2.8)
    d = findInterval(z, breaks)
    d = fast_table(d, 10)
    d = d/sum(d) * 100
    d = cumsum(d)[1:9]
    d = as.list(d)
  }
  names(d) = paste0("zpcum", 1:9)
  metrics = c( d)
  return(metrics)
}

metric2=grid_metrics(ctgn.i, ~myMetrics2(z, res=1)
#> Processing [=========================================] 100% (1/1) eta:  0s
#> Error: could not find function "fast_table"
```

Comment: `fast_table` is an internal function of the lidR package. You took the source code of the package and put it in the your global environment. You cannot expect this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to write a function like this. But it is hard to say because your code example is not related *at all* to your text description. I based this answer on your text description.

```r
f = function(z) {
  n02.3 = sum(z >= 0.2 & z <= 3)
  n = length(z)
  return(list(ratio = n02.3/n))
}

metric2 = grid_metrics(ctgn.i, ~f(z), res = 1)
```